# Android picture compression without loading fully into memory

Tags: android, performance, image-compression

Is there any way to compress image without fully loading it into memory?
As I understand `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` and similar methods load everything in memory and only after loading entire picture it can be compressed via `Bitmap.compress`

My task is to send picture from android to server

Comment: Unless the Linux provides a method to compress image, I don't think it is possible. Compression means calculation.If calculate in Android, then it requires Android memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder) to read only a part of the original image, then compress and upload each part separately.

> BitmapRegionDecoder can be used to decode a rectangle region from an image. BitmapRegionDecoder is particularly useful when an original image is large and you only need parts of the image.
>
> To create a BitmapRegionDecoder, call newInstance(...). Given a
>   BitmapRegionDecoder, users can call decodeRegion() repeatedly to get a
>   decoded Bitmap of the specified region.